# how do I upload an image to Parse.com from my local disk using node.js

Tags: node.js, file-upload, parse-platform

I have an image that is saved to disk, and I want to use Node to upload that image to Parse.com. I'm wondering if there is a way to do this and if so, how I would go about doing so.

Comment: Please note, if your question could be solved by a Google Search (https://www.google.com/#q=node.js+upload+to+parse.com), the it probably shouldn't belong here.